# Github: Require approval to merge 1 particular file

Tags: github

Is it possible to set a rule on github:

- Require approval from Mr.X
- if Foo.Txt has been modified

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Specify the required approver of a file in a [CODEOWNERS file](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners), and then set up [branch protection rules](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-protected-branches/about-protected-branches) to require that merges to that branch be approved by the code owners.